# Windows Server 2008 is connected to network but Internet Explorer can't browse

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, internet-connection

I'm creating a Virtual Machine using Hyper-V with Windows Server 2008. The VM is ok, I can connect all my network and I can ping any address with success. But when I try to browse using the default internet explorer, it says something like the server is ok but isn't responding.

I already turned-off the enhaced security system. There is something else I need to do?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The windows update isn't working too. Like I said, I can ping google and anything else. If I put the google ip on the browser, it didn't reach too. So, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my switch for network connect of Hyper V and created a new one.
Used this post as refer

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19359-hyper-v-virtual-switch-manager.html